# Recommended sender name when sharing an address

Tags: email

We have an application that is used for client management, which has a generic e-mail account attached to it (info@example.com). All e-mail that is sent here, is received by our application (processed using PHP). Mail will be replied by various employees, depending on the issue. So sometimes John answers, and sometimes Peter. Currently, the "Sender" header of the mail will be set to:

Company Name / John
Company Name / Peter

etc.

That allows people to see who they are communicating with, we figured. However, it turns out that some e-mail clients by default do not show you the address that is used to send the mail once you have added this to the address book (often also done automatically when replying). So this means that if John sends from info@example.com, the mail header will say "Company Name / John", but the email client says "Company name / Peter", because the client was in touch with Peter before.

The simple solution is to only put "Company Name" as sender, but I prefer not to lose this detail. So I was wondering if others have had the same issue, and perhaps know other tricks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tell Peter and John not to reply the original email, and send a new one from their respective account with a copy of the original message.